# Create foreign key with jpa

Tags: mysql, spring, jpa

So when I run my project the `User` table and the `Doc` table are created, but I dont see the foreign key for `User` table in the `Doc` table.

As you can see I have both `ManyToOne` and `OneToMany` annotations, and yet the foreign key for User isn't created.

How can I solve this ?

Comment: do you have Partenaire id in doc table?

Comment: Partenaire is not a table as you can see Partenaire extends User so its SINGLE_TABLE strategy all Partenaire's properties will be added to User Table which will be discriminated by the field `TYPE_USER` instead of creating a new table for it

Comment: trying adding  @JoinColumn(name = "XX") in many to one

Answer (score 1):

You need to add @JoinColumn(name = "ID Column Name") annotation along with the @ManyToOne or @OneToMany annotation as ZaoTaoBao mentioned. This annotation determines the name of the column which is to be used as FK.

Refer to this link for more details: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/JoinColumn.html

Comment: Nope this doesn't work JoinColumn only renamed the field to be used to reference the other table but without the FK