# How to create a foreign key using single table strategy

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have two entities `User` and `Partner`, the `Partner` entity extends `User`.

I'm working with single table strategy, so in the database the `User` is the only table that will be created.

I have another entity which is `Doc`, this entity has a `ManyToOne` relation with the `Partner` entity.

So I want when I lunch my application to create two tables in the database `User` and `Doc`, the table `Doc` will have then a foreign key references the PK of the `User` table, but it doesn't do this, instead it only creates a column but without the reference key.

**Doc**

```
@Entity
public class Doc implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String path;
    @Column(name="CREATION_TS", columnDefinition="TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private Calendar dateUploaded;

    @ManyToOne
    private Partenaire partenaire;

    public Doc(Document type, String name, String path, Calendar dateUploaded) {
        this.type = type;
        this.name = name;
        this.path = path;
        this.dateUploaded = dateUploaded;
    }

    //setters/getters

    @JsonIgnore
    @XmlTransient
    public Partenaire getPartenaire() {
        return partenaire;
    }

    @JsonSetter
    public void setPartenaire(Partenaire partenaire) {
        this.partenaire = partenaire;
    }
}
```

**Partenaire**

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("UP")
@XmlType(name = "UP")
public class Partenaire extends User implements Serializable {

//properties

@OneToMany(mappedBy="partenaire")
    private Collection<Doc> docs;

public Collection<Doc> getDocs() {
        return docs;
    }

    public void setDocs(Collection<Doc> docs) {
        this.docs = docs;
    }

}
```

**User**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="users")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="TYPE_USER",discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.STRING,length=2)

@XmlSeeAlso({Candidat.class, Partenaire.class})
public class User implements Serializable {
@Id
private String username;
//properties ... 

}
```

How can I solve this ?

## Edit :

this is my table structure :

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.5.1
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Host: 127.0.0.1
-- Generation Time: May 27, 2016 at 12:52 PM
-- Server version: 10.1.9-MariaDB
-- PHP Version: 5.6.15

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;

--
-- Database: `db_myfme`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `doc`
--

CREATE TABLE `doc` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `creation_ts` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `path` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `username` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `type` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--

--
-- Indexes for table `doc`
--
ALTER TABLE `doc`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD KEY `FK_getdvvdhvurquqocgh0i9cdgl` (`type`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for dumped tables
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `doc`
--
ALTER TABLE `doc`
  MODIFY `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
--
-- Constraints for dumped tables
--

--
-- Constraints for table `doc`
--
ALTER TABLE `doc`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_getdvvdhvurquqocgh0i9cdgl` FOREIGN KEY (`type`) REFERENCES `document` (`code_document`);

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

Comment: which JPA implementation? because some certainly do create FKs

Comment: @BillyFrost yes I'm using Spring Data Jpa, but it only creates the field without the foreign key

Comment: Spring Data JPA is NOT A JPA IMPLEMENTATION. JPA implementations are things like DataNucleus, EclipseLink, Hibernate, OpenJPA.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create foreign key with jpa](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37466016/create-foreign-key-with-jpa)

Comment: You shouldn't use XML and JPA annotations in one class.

Comment: Can you Show the created tablestructure?

Comment: @BillyFrost yes indeed what I meant is that Spring Data Jpa uses Hibernate by default

Comment: @Jens check my edit

Comment: @AimadMAJDOU Where the column type comes from? what is the value of `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto`?

Comment: @Jens I didn't put the whole properties of the Doc entity since I only have the problem with the foreign key which references for the user table but the other references are getting generated as in case of the column type

Answer (score 0):

Since creating a sepparate partenaire-class and annotating it as @Entity, it will create a new table "Partenaire" unless you name the table separatly. I think this is not your intention, because you already have a table "User".
What you wish to do, I assume, is to call the User as partenaire from your "Doc"-class:

```
@ManyToOne
private User partenaire;
```

And (in User-class):

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="partenaire")
private Collection<Doc> docs;
```

If you correctly implement this in your controller, I think your problem would be solved..
Unless, of course, there is another reason to make a sepparate class for partenaire?